# linear model using significant outcomes of linear model

Tags: regression, classification, feature-selection, linear-model, regression-strategies

I am getting confused about a couple of techniques that I'd like to discuss:

I am using an R package that in turn depends on the [limma](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf) package. I tried reading the docs, but I can't grasp what is going on. I understand that, for example, instead of performing a t-test for each feature of a set, it uses a linear model - I have no idea whether this will be important. In any case, the package uses limma under the hood to find differential features out of let's say 400K features for 1K samples

I know how to find differential features using my package based on limma, but for 400K samples we assume about 20K (5%) significant outcomes - which is about what I end up with.

But what If you need a small panel of features that can predict the outcome: the sample status? I can't seem to find the answer to this question: Can or should you build a (penalized) model with predictors you already know are differential between your samples?

And in case creating a model from differential features is not a good idea: Should you instead build a model using the original 400K features, or can I go straight to sampling a set of the 20K differential features to predict outcome and comparing ROC AUC values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are both statistical and practical issues here.

[LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) is a well established procedure for selecting a predictively useful subset from a large number of features. In your application, with a yes/no outcome, this would be done in the context of a logistic regression model. The number of features selected depends on a penalty factor, whose value is typically chosen to optimize a measure of performance as assessed by cross-validation. See [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) for an introduction to this and to many other modeling approaches.

Note that AUC or classification accuracy are not usually the best measures of performance for selecting the penalty factor; minimizing deviance, the default in the [`glmnet` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=glmnet) in R, is preferred. With a logistic model developed this way, providing probabilities of class membership instead of a simple yes/no prediction, you can trade off between false-positive and false-negative classifications based on their different costs.

A potential difficulty with LASSO or any other feature-selection method is that the particular features selected may vary widely from study to study. With more features than samples there are necessarily correlations among different features, so those chosen from a set of highly correlated features will depend on the luck of the draw in terms of the samples, random analysis errors, and so forth. That's not necessarily a drawback for predictive ability, but it does mean that you should refrain from claiming that the selected features are the only important features.

If you are trying to develop a limited test panel to replace a large-scale analysis like the microarrays for which `limma` was designed, you also need to take into account practical issues in designing and performing the new tests. For example, in microarray studies, a gene high up on the differentially expressed list or selected by LASSO might only be expressed at a very low level and thus difficult to use in practice. So there will necessarily be some back-and-forth between statistics and experiments in coming up with a useful limited panel of predictors.

You might want to read [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4656721/) on breast cancer classification, in particular on tests to predict the probability of disease recurrence. Molecular classifications originally developed from microarray data have subsequently been reduced to small panels of genes whose expression can be determined with commercial tests on standard pathology specimens. As the paper notes, few particular genes are shared among the competing commercial tests, emphasizing the somewhat arbitrary nature of the selection of a useful set of features from a very large set.